# Tar all files in the directory that begin with

Tags: bash, tar

Consider a directory with multiple files. Among them, there are files that begin with `ABC` and `XYZ`.

I want to create a `.tar.gz` that includes all files that begin with `ABC` and `XYZ`, but not other files.

What's the command to do so?

Comment: Try to show your effort in solving YOUR issues. And what errors you need help with.. not just ask for ready solutions...

Answer (score 0):

With bash

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

files=(ABC* XYZ*)
tar -czvf files.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```